# Apache Flume file size

Tags: flume

I am using flume-ng and its HDFS sink. Now if I add some files into the given folder, it is also stored in the HDFS automatically. It is working fine; however I notice the size of the files in the HDFS is quite small. So if I put a 1GB file into the given folder, it is stored in the HDFS by several hundreds of files. Can I make the size of file in the HDFS more bigger? How can I configure it in flume-conf.properties?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the `hdfs.rollSize`.

There is a open jira that will help increasing the hdfs block size https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2003